# The name 'TemplateFileManager' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, t4

I'm playing around a bit with C# and T4. I'm completely new to it but I'm making progress I think.

But now I want to generate more than 1 output file from my template. This is described very nice on these 2 links: https://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/forum/forum.aspx?g=posts&t=1334 & https://igormsouza.wordpress.com/2016/04/25/how-to-generate-multiples-files-from-a-single-template-t4-in-vs/.

But I have a problem; I have this code:

```
<#@ include file="TemplateFileManagerV2.1.ttinclude" #>
    
<#
    var manager = TemplateFileManager.Create(this);
```

This is exactly the same as on the links I think. But what happens is this error:

Compiling transformation: The name 'TemplateFileManager' does not exist in the current context.

I've been Googling for this error and then I see many things about that you need to add a using statement or something similar. But as a starter I don't know which code must be included and I tend to believe that the include must do the trick. But the error says it's not.

TemplateFileManagerV2.1.ttinclude is included in my project and located on the directory where is pointed to...

Is there anyone who can tell me what I do wrong;

Comment: Can you provide a full T4 example with all directives? Might be missing something. Maybe not the right answer to your question, but I achieved this by a more manual apporach: https://tim-maes.com/2019/08/12/tutorial-generate-seperate-files-from-a-t4-template/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. There was a strange wrong content in my TemplateFileManagerV2.1.ttinclude.